# Cycle2 doesn't trigger "cycle-initialized"

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I want to run function when slide is finished and before the slider even starts to work. My code is as follows:

```
$('#slider').cycle({
    swipe: true,
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    slides: '> article',
    timeout: 7500
});

$('#slider').on( 'cycle-initialized cycle-after', function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag ) {
    $(this).find('.loader').addClass('loaded');
    $(this).find('.display-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
    $(this).find('.tablet-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
    $(this).find('.mobile-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
});

$('#slider').on( 'cycle-before', function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag ) {
    $(this).find('.loader').removeClass('loaded');
    $(this).find('.display-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
    $(this).find('.tablet-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
    $(this).find('.mobile-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
});
```

All works great, except `cycle-initialized` - it doesn't fire. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the event bindings before you create the cycle, otherwise the function isn't bound to the cycle-initialized event until after the cycle is already initialized, and it won't get called.

Just change it to this and it will work:

```
$('#slider').on( 'cycle-initialized cycle-after', function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag ) {
    $(this).find('.loader').addClass('loaded');
    $(this).find('.display-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
    $(this).find('.tablet-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
    $(this).find('.mobile-selector').removeClass('out-of-place').addClass('in-place');
});

$('#slider').on( 'cycle-before', function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag ) {
    $(this).find('.loader').removeClass('loaded');
    $(this).find('.display-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
    $(this).find('.tablet-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
    $(this).find('.mobile-selector').removeClass('in-place').addClass('out-of-place');
});

$('#slider').cycle({
    swipe: true,
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    slides: '> article',
    timeout: 7500
});
```